# ms access reports and queries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Good day

I am creating a bill of materials program.

There are two main tables named Products and Sub_Products.

In the Products table, the fields are (Product_Name, Code). In the Sub_Products table, the fields are (Code, Sub_Name).

The tables are linked with code, i.e.: one product is made up of many sub_products, each sub_product is a product as well, making it have many sub_products.

I have created a query that reads a product and gets its sub_products. I need a query to compare Sub_Name with Product_Name and then check more sub_products, continuing until no more sub_products are found.

I created a query that gets product_name than gets component_name, than another query to change component_name to product_name and get its component

So every time I have to manually create a query to see the next level, is there no other way..

Quert sql statement for 4th Query---------

SELECT [Query3rd].Component_Name, products101.Our_Product_Code, products101.Product_Name, Sub_Products101.Component_Name FROM (Query3rd INNER JOIN products101 ON [Query3rd].Component_Name=products101.Product_Name) INNER JOIN Sub_Products101 ON products101.Our_Product_Code=Sub_Products101.Our_Product_Code WHERE ((([Query3rd].Component_Name)=(products101.Product_Name)));

Answer (score 1):

If you stick with the [Adjacency list model](http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm) that you are currently using then yes, there no other way.

Your problem would be solved if you switched to the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) but there would be other trade-offs.

I suggest you read the book 'Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties' by Joe Celko and make an informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

See my reply to your previous question.  Which has now been deleted.

This is the standard Bill of Materials problem.  See [Modules: Bill Of Materials](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0027.htm) although I'm sure there are many other examples out there.

Comment: Tony,
This is his only question asked.  Where is your answer?
Seth

Comment: Then he deleted his other posting.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem in the past I would use a big temp table with fields like level1, level2, level3, etc.  Level1, of course would where you would put the "root" objects...that is, objects that don't have a parent.

Then you create a function that calls itself recursively and fills out the table into all of the levels.  It is sort of yucky but it works.

It has been a while since I did that ... I will see if I can find the function somewhere but I doubt I will be able to get my hands on it.

But I bet someone else has that code more available.  Anyone?  Anyone?

Seth

PS...BOMs display great in a treeview control.